# Optical Logic Gates using Polarisers

Tags: visible-light, laser, computational-physics, polarization

I am trying to build an optical logic circuit using the horizontal or vertical orientations of light as the two binary states and laser as the source. Before I ask you my question I wanted to first share how I designed the NOT Gate.

[image]

## NOT Gate

To explain the working let's assume I send in a horizontally oriented beam of light. This beam splits into two beams. Because it is horizontally oriented, the first split beam won't enter the V Polarizer and gets blocked. The second split beam enters the H Polarizer and consequently gets vertically oriented at the end and the lower LDR detects the light, notifying us that it is now in V state.

## My Problem

Now, I am not able to figure out another combination of polarizers for AND and OR Gate. Can anyone help me in giving me a lead?

Comment: You don't even say what the logical 0 and 1 are.  How should one answer the question?

Comment: I have mentioned that in the second and third line. Read properly.

Comment: I see.  (Note that "second and third line" depends on the screen!).   But then, why don't you just use a lambda/2 plate for the not gate?  Your setup seems unnecessarily complicated!

Comment: I don't have access to wave plates, only linear polarizers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need the state of one beam to affect the state of another. This is a nonlinear effect requiring a potentially complex arrangement of optics and materials to make it efficient enough to be practical. First, read about nonlinear optics, then try looking up all-optical switches, for example. You won’t be able to do it with a few polarizers since they are linear optical elements.

Also, you can improve your NOT gate by switching your design with a single half-waveplate oriented at 45$^\circ$. This new design would be 100% efficient.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by changing the NOT with a single waveplate at 45 degrees?

Comment: @Bhavesh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate#Half-wave_plate